# Adding whitespace to the ends of textwrapping?

Tags: python, whitespace, word-wrap

I'm looking to wrap a paragraph with a limit of 80 characters, however if there is a necessary break (break long words set to false) and the line total is now 71 for example, how do I add 9 characters worth of white space to fill it out to 80 characters, for each line that this occurs.

I'm looking to use either the fill function of textwrapper rather than wrap, or anything that does it similarly. (ie. no lists)

Comment: So, you don't want to use a function outside of `textwrap`, regardless of whether `textwrap` has the function you want?

Comment: No, I am willing to use outside functions, just those that are similar to fill, and not wrap.

Comment: Converting between `wrap()` and `fill()` is a oneliner. One conveniently included in the documentation for `fill()`. Use Nick Bastin's answer and join the lines after.

Comment: You know it had occurred to me already that making a wrap list would give the desired effect, except that it's in a list.  Turning it back into a string eluded me.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just postprocess the result:

```
for line in textwrap.wrap(some_text, 80, break_long_words=False):
  yield "%-80s" % (line)
```

Obviously if you have a lot of this to do you might want to create your own `TextWrapper` instance, but I suspect you already are familiar with the [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html) documentation.